# Object of given class callable once, but not again

Tags: python-2.7, matplotlib

My code runs fine with one rectangle, but as soon as I add a second rectangle, it says "'point' object is not callable" despite successfully calling it for the first one. I have ran enough tests with different variations on the rectangles to conclude that the only cause is the fact that it is now more than one rectangle it is trying to create. Can anyone please help?

Here's the start of the code, which is used to define different elements and their parameters.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy

elementset = []
pointxs = []
pointys = []

class point(object):
    """General point in 2d space, with stored x value and y value.
    Created and used in elements to give them shape.
    """

    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = float(x)
        self.y = float(y)
        self.isAnchor = False

    def __repr__(self):
        return "(%d, %d)" % (self.x, self.y)

class element(object):
    """Most general class used to define any element to be used in
    the cross-section being worked with. Used as a basis for more
    specific classes. Has a coordinate value and a number of points that
    need to be generated for the general case.
    """

    def __init__(self, anchor_x, anchor_y):
        self.num_points = 0
        self.anchor_x = float(anchor_x)
        self.anchor_y = float(anchor_y)
        elementset.append(self)

    def getinfo(self):
        """Used for debugging, prints all general info for the element.
        Never called in the actual code."""
        print "Number of points: " + str(self.num_points)
        print "x coordinate: " + str(self.anchor_x)
        print "y coordinate: " + str(self.anchor_y)

    def debug(self):
        self.getinfo()

class rectangle(element):
    """A rectangle, assumed to be aligned such that all sides are
    either vertical or horizontal. Calls/assigns variables
    created in the element class via super().
    """

    def __init__(self, anchor_x, anchor_y, width, height):
        super(rectangle, self).__init__(anchor_x, anchor_y)
        self.title = "rectangle"
        self.num_points = 4
        self.width = float(width)
        self.height = float(height)
        self.generate()
        self.calculate()

    def generate(self):
        """Creates the points that frame the rectangle using coordinates.
        For a rectangle, the anchor point represents the bottom left point."""
        self.anchor = point(self.anchor_x, self.anchor_y)
        self.pointxpos = point(self.anchor_x + self.width, self.anchor_y)
        self.pointxypos = point(self.anchor_x + self.width, self.anchor_y + self.height)
        self.pointypos = point(self.anchor_x, self.anchor_y + self.height)
        self.points = [self.anchor, self.pointxpos, self.pointxypos, self.pointypos]
        self.plotpoints = [self.anchor, self.pointxpos, self.pointxypos, self.pointypos, self.anchor]
```

And here is the function that calls these (with only 1 rectangle defined):

```
ar = rectangle(0,0,50,20)

for element in elementset:
    if isinstance(element,rectangle):
        element.generate()
        for point in element.plotpoints:
            pointxs.append(point.x)
            pointys.append(point.y)
        plt.plot(pointxs,pointys, linewidth=3)

    elif isinstance(element,square):
        pass #placeholder
    elif isinstance(element,circle):
        pass #placeholder
    elif isinstance(element,semicircle):
        pass #placeholder

plt.show()
```

This is successful, plotting a 50x20 rectangle with the bottom left corner at (0,0).

but if i were to add another element below ar:

```
ar = rectangle(0,0,50,20)
br = rectangle(50,20,10,10)
```

it throws "'point' object is not callable".
I'm honestly stumped by this, so thank you so much in advance for any given help.

Answer (score 0):

I wonder why this is even successful for the first rectangle. The reason may be that you don't show a true [minimal complete verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

In any case, the problem is as simple as that: **Never use the same name for a class as for a (loop-) variable.**

I.e. the following works:

```
ar = rectangle(0,0,50,20)
br = rectangle(23,16,22,13)

elementset.append(ar)
elementset.append(br)

for elefant in elementset:
    if isinstance(elefant,rectangle):
        elefant.generate()
        for wombat in elefant.plotpoints:
            pointxs.append(wombat.x)
            pointys.append(wombat.y)
        plt.plot(pointxs,pointys, linewidth=3)
```

...apart from the fact that all objects will be connected by a line, but that is probably a different question.